# Iterating through Pandas data series

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Here is my code;

I have a csv file (excel sheet) with dates, lats, and longs. I also have a column with the days as the day-of-the-year index (integers between 0 and 360). I want to loop through the rows (by using an index) and print out the erc variable corresponding to the date, lat and lon. When I do this I get the IndexError listed below... what do I need to correct?

```
    from netCDF4 import Dataset
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd


    data = pd.read_csv('Lindley.csv')
    print(data.head(5))

    POIlat = data.Lat
    POIlon = data.Long
    name = data.Date
    date = data.DayIndex

    nc = Dataset('erc_2019.nc')
    print(nc)

    lat = nc.variables['lat'][:]
    lon = nc.variables['lon'][:]
    erc = nc.variables['energy_release_component-g'][:]
    #print(nc.variables)

    x, y = np.meshgrid(lon, lat)

    for i in range(len(POIlat)):
         print(erc[date[i], POIlat[i], POIlon[i]])
```

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Comment: What the error wants to tell you is that you won't be able to use `date[i], POIlat[i], POIlon[i]` to call a certain element of `erc`. What is the `shape` of `erc`, i.e. what does `erc.shape` give you?

Comment: I accidentally had a space in front of the first value date[i] called; it works now thanks!